# Angular 10: Set the default value of dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

How do I set the default value of dropdown (All Person), which is bound with the below list:

```
    let persons = [
      {id: "-1", name: "All Person"},
      {id: "10", name: "Mayank"},
      {id: "20", name: "Prachi"}
    ];
```

Dropdown UI code snippet mentioned below:

```
<ng-select formControlName="person" (change)="statsChange()">
      <ng-option *ngFor="let p of persons" [value]="p.id">{{p.name}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Please provide your input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set the formControl to any one of the values defined in your dropdown options.

**this.form.get('person').setValue(id);**

So if persons = *[{id:1,name:'alex'},{id:2, name:'john'}]*.

and if you want to set john as the default value then you can set the following: **this.form.get('person').setValue(2);**

Comment: Thanks, but can't we set the all option during drop-down rendering ?

Comment: this.form.get('person').setValue(-1); will do the trick